# "Length" being the longer dimension

Tags: meaning

I recently came across the definition for length - Merriam-Webster defines it as

> the longer or longest dimension of an object

(other dictionaries have similar definitions).

This is not how I think I use it, and I'm wondering if I'm in the minority.  To me, 'length' refers to the more natural dimension and 'width' to the less natural dimension.  If the object has a natural up orientation, that dimension is usually 'height' and the others are 'length' and 'width'.

For example, a squat cylinder, if not placed flat on the ground, would be short (its length would be small) and wide (its width would be great).  Also, a chair with enormous armrests but only seating space for one person might not be long but it could be very wide.

Is this definition of length wrong or incomplete or am I using 'length' in an unusual manner? Obviously, I don't expect Merriam-Webster to change the definition - it should be both correct and simple, and my definition might be complex.

Comment: I think you'd start dropping 'length' with your cylinder (height and radius) and chair (height, width and depth). A square is obviously as broad as it is long, so labelling one side the 'length' would be arbitrary. // With a natural axis, perhaps the length could be smaller than the width. A very squat square-cross-sectional sausage, perhaps. Rare.

Comment: Not every three dimensional object naturally has a "length". In practice, things like ***chairs*** rarely do (unless they're effectively "loungers"). It's a bit pointless trying to find a generic definition for the "length" dimension of inappropriate objects.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe a more natural usage, then: In D&D, if a creature has a breath weapon it might be described as affecting a 30 foot long, 5 foot wide line emanating from that creature - normal usage.  Then an attack which can hit creatures in the square in front of you and the two squares adjacent to that creature can be described as being 5 feet long and 15 feet wide, and I think that's the most natural way to describe it.

Comment: D&D: _a more natural usage_? Note that reputable dictionaries carry out controlled surveys to see how words are most commonly used, and either quite acceptably don't pick up, or disregard niche usages. Jargon, in gaming, chemistry, archaeology, maths, law, technology, art, antiques ... , belongs properly in dedicated works (and ELU looks at standard usages).

Comment: Try to see (and bear in mind at all times) the difference in meaning of a word in general English usage and specific domain usage or contextual usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have a point.  I note that the definition provided in the Cambridge English online dictionary is similar.

> the measurement of something from end to end or along its longest side:

It is difficult to provide an ideal definition that covers all circumstances.  In geometry, for example, in its purest form, *length* is a property of a line - any line.  So we can describe lines in terms their two ends.  So a rectangle, ABCD can be described as having parallel lines, AB and CD, of equal **length** and parallel lines, AD and BC of equal length and at right angles to AB and CD.  There is no need for a reference to *width*.

In the case of of triangles, all three lines have a 'length', as do the sides of any other polygon.

However, when it comes to area you will often encounter *length* by *breadth/width*.  And volume is often referred to as *length times breadth times height*. *Height* **is** referred to in triangles, when the area is calculated as length times vertical *height*.

I think the Merriam and Cambridge idea of *length* of a two-dimensional object as the longer or longest sides.  But essentially what we are concerned with, not mentioned in the dictionaries I have checked, is *orientation*, though I have not found that word used

And this seems to be the point you are making, in speaking of an extremely wide armchair.  We (most of us) do think of that as *wide* rather than *long*.  In the end, it comes down to how we 'stand' to the thing described.  And the language used varies considerably.  For example, for furniture, when speaking of cabinetry, specifications tend to speak of *width, **depth** (front to back) and height*.  We face them; they are against a wall, so that there is a sense of width rather than breadth or length.

Nevertheless, there is some truth in saying that of, say, a table, the *length* is (are) its *longer* side(s) and the *width/breadth* is (are) the shorter.

Comment: I agree. The definition really refers to two-dimensional objects — one wouldn't refer to the length of a skyscraper, for example, although one could refer to the length of the Great Wall of China. But length clearly derives from "long", and probably was used originally only in the context of two-dimensionality. Even MW's use of "side" has this implicit suggestion.